# How can i group together nodes belonging to a same type (color) in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

In order to make a better data-visualization i need to have all nodes belonging to a same type one next to the other.
I don't know how to define the layout.

This is my script:

```
    nodes<-bind_rows(node1, node2)

g_doc<- graph_from_data_frame(data_tot_net, vertices = nodes, directed = F)
 
V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type != "PUNTO"]$size <- 1060*data_tot$`perc_ fatturato`

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "PUNTO"]$size <- 150

E(g_doc)$weight<-100000*data_tot$BOLLE

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "PUNTO"]$color <- "firebrick1"

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "A"]$color <- "gold1"

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "H"]$color <- "chartreuse"

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "L"]$color <- "chocolate2"

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "B"]$color <- "darkorchid1"

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "F"]$color <- "darkslategray1"

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "A"]$color <- "pink"

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "G"]$color <- "dodgerblue2"

V(g_doc)[V(g_doc)$type == "D"]$color <- "gray58"

V(g_doc)$label.cex <- seq(0.5,0.5,length.out=6) 

g1 <- ggraph(g_doc, layout = "stress") +
  geom_edge_link0(aes(edge_width = weight), edge_colour = "grey66") + geom_node_point(aes(size = size), fill = V(g_doc)$color, colour = "white", shape = 21) + geom_node_text(aes(label = name), size = 2.5) +
  scale_edge_width(range = c(0.5, 2.5)) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 38)) +
  theme_graph()

plot(g1)
```

Here is:
[image: my network]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Showing your own effort drastically improves your chances to receive a good (or any) answer.

Comment: I have added my script. Hope to be clear